How to resolve RSA dispose error when validating JWT with JwtSecurityTokenHandler in C#
I am using .NET 8.0 and encountering a Cannot access a disposed object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey error about 50% of the time when using the using statement or finally block with rsa.Dispose(). If I do not use using or finally, the error does not occur at all.
Here is my code:
RSA rsa = RSA.Create(); // OR using(RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
try
{

    rsa.ImportParameters(new RSAParameters
    {
        Modulus = bytesN, 
        Exponent = bytesE 
    }); 

    var rsaSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa)
    {
        KeyId = strKid 
    };

    JwtConfiguration jwtConfiguration = _configurationUtil.GetJwtConfiguration("Kakao");

    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = jwtConfiguration.ValidateIssuer, 
        ValidIssuer = jwtConfiguration.ValidIssuer,
        ValidateAudience = jwtConfiguration.ValidateAudience, 
        ValidAudience = jwtConfiguration.ValidAudience, 
        ValidateLifetime = jwtConfiguration.ValidateLifetime,
        RequireExpirationTime = jwtConfiguration.RequireExpirationTime, 
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = jwtConfiguration.ValidateIssuerSigningKey, 
        IssuerSigningKey = rsaSecurityKey,
        TryAllIssuerSigningKeys = jwtConfiguration.TryAllIssuerSigningKeys, 
    };

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler(); 

    var claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(strIdToken, tokenValidationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
    var jwtSecurityToken = validatedToken as JwtSecurityToken; 

    string nonce = jwtSecurityToken!.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "nonce")?.Value!;
    if (nonce != oauthConfiguration.Nonce)
        throw new Exception("NONCE ERROR");

    strId = jwtSecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value!; 
    strEmail = jwtSecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "email")?.Value!; 
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    response.RESULT_CODE = "F000";
    response.RESULT_MSG = e.Message; 
    return Page(); 
}
finally
{
    rsa.Dispose();
}

And here is the exact error message I receive:
IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey, KeyId: 'sameKid', InternalId: 'internalId'. , KeyId: sameKid
'. 
Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '1'. 
Number of keys in Configuration: '0'. 
Matched key was in 'TokenValidationParameters'. 
kid: 'sameKid'. 
Exceptions caught:
 'System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSABCrypt'.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSABCrypt.GetKey()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSABCrypt.VerifyHash(ReadOnlySpan`1 hash, ReadOnlySpan`1 signature, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricAdapter.VerifyUsingSpan(Boolean isRSA, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes, Byte[] signature)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricAdapter.VerifyRsa(Byte[] bytes, Byte[] signature)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricAdapter.Verify(Byte[] bytes, Byte[] signature)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider.Verify(Byte[] input, Byte[] signature)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(Byte[] encodedBytes, Byte[] signature, SecurityKey key, String algorithm, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, BaseConfiguration configuration)
'.
token: '[Security Artifact of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/SecurityArtifactLogging.]'. See https://aka.ms/IDX10511 for details.

How can I properly manage the disposal of the RSA object to avoid this error?
I tried using the using statement and finally block to ensure the RSA object is disposed of properly. I also attempted not using using or finally to avoid the disposal error.
I expected that the signing key would always remain the same, allowing the process to complete without errors and for the validation to succeed. I am not sure why the RSA object is being disposed.

Can you show the method signature around this code?

'n' and 'e' are obtained from the real-time public key of the Kakao login API, where the 'kid' of the JWT to be verified matches.
byte[] bytesE = Base64UrlDecoder.Base64UrlDecode(strE);```

Please don't put relevant information in the comments but edit your question. No one want's to read all comments.

Change your rsaSecurityKey object like this
 var rsaSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa) { KeyId = strKid, CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory { CacheSignatureProviders = false } };
The problem is with the caching of the signature provider.

This solution fix similar problem with ECDsaSecurityKey for me. Thanks.
